# how to fetch users without a specific meta value wp_user_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem finding the right solution for this issue, basically i am trying to retrieve all user records from the wp db that don't have a specific meta value or meta field - ex: meta_key=field_name & meta_value=null

This is my code:

```
  $args_sub = array(
        'number' => 600,
        'role' => 'Subscriber',
        'meta_key' => '_is_notified',enter code here
        'meta_value' => NULL,
        'meta_compare' => '=',
    );
    $user_query_subscribers = new WP_User_Query( $args_sub );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `'NOT EXISTS'` comparison operator:

```
$args = array(
    'number' => 600,
    'role' => 'Subscriber',
    'meta_key' => '_is_notified',
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
);
$user_query_subscribers = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```